# Multiple labels in Cref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

Following is a simple code to show my problem with the `cleveref` package.  When using multiple labels it breaks on the second label...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}

\begin{document}
\begin{lemma} \label{lem:fast}
a
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma} \label{lem:slow}
b
\end{lemma}

\Cref{lem:fast} \\
\Cref{lem:slow} \\
\Cref{lem:fast, lem:slow} \\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 23):

Omit the space after the comma.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}

\begin{document}
\begin{lemma} \label{lem:fast}
a
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma} \label{lem:slow}
b
\end{lemma}

\Cref{lem:fast} \\
\Cref{lem:slow} \\
\Cref{lem:fast,lem:slow} \\% <--- no space after the comma

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the first is a lemma (labeled lem) and the second is a theorem (labeled thm), then \Cref{lem,thm} gives "Lemma 1 and theorem 2". Why is it not capitalizing the first letter of theorem? Any fix for this, other than using "\Cref{lem} and \Cref{thm}"?

Comment: @JansonA.J Cleverref handles capitalization, that's why there are two commands `\Cref` and `\cref`. The idea is to use the command that fits grammatically, not to work around capitalization by simply always using `\Cref`. If you always want to capitalize theorems, the intended way is to set it globally using the `\crefname` command (e.g., `\crefname{@theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}`).

Comment: Is there a way to obtain "Lemmas 1 **or** 2" and not "Lemmas 1 **and** 2"?

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this problem is to remove the space after the `,`, this has been suggested by lockstep already.

Now, why is the `space` there important?

When a label is defined, space does matter, since in the very end, `\newlabel` uses

`\@namedef{}{}` effectively, where `space` actually is allowed in the first argument, i.e. in the sense that a command sequence is defined that has space characters in its name.

`\cref` (or `\Cref`) try to get the relevant stored label content as being splitted by the comma separated list, where the space character is regarded to belong to the label, so `\cref{foo,foobar}` and `\cref{foo, foobar}` give different results.

The same issue would be given with `\ref{ foo}` when the label is called `foo` and not `_foo`, where `_` stands for space here, however, without the comma separated list feature then.